# How to use a variable in a function expression which is injected in a page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to inject a function into a webpage via Chrome extension content script by:

```
function inject(code) {
    var actualCode = '(' + code + ')();';
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = actualCode;
    (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
    script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
}

var myObj = person;  // myObj/person is passed in from elsewhere
var fn = function() {
    alert(myObj.name);
};
inject(fn); // myObj undefined
```

My issue is, since fn is a function expression, I can't pass in myObj.personName.  So my question is, how can I construct a function expression that includes a variable?  Do I do some sort of string concatenation instead?

I also tried to pass the object to the function, as follows:

```
function inject(code, myObj) {
    var actualCode = '(' + code + ')(' + myObj +');';
    ...
```

But this did not work, and caused a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error.

Related: [Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script)

Comment: _"since fn is a function expression, I can't pass in myObj.personName"_ - Why not? You can do this: `(function(param){...})(paramValue);` (so you should be able to modify your code to make something like that happen).

Comment: It depends on the scope. If `myObj` is declared in the same scope as `inject`, it should work.

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried doing something like that. If I do `var fn = (function(p){...})(param);` it'll execute the function instead of passing the actual function expression. I also tried doing something like `function inject(func, myObj) { var code = '(' + func + ')(' + myObj + ');'; ... }`, but that absolutely did not work, lol, it threw _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier_

Comment: @bfavaretto Unfortunately, it's not defined in the same scope as inject.  Everything is wrapped in a event listener function and myObj is passed from the event itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach was almost correct. The problem is that the following

```
var code = '(' + func + ')(' + myObj + ');'   // results in
var code = '(function(){})([object Object])'
```

To solve this, just use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
var code = '(' + func + ')(' + JSON.stringify(myObj) + ');';
```

Comment: I've updated [the answer at "Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/938089?building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script), and added a section at the end which explains this method with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var actualCode = new Function( code )();
```

Comment: It takes a string: `new Function( 'return 1+2' )() //=> 3`

Answer (score 1):

You can [post messages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication) in and back between event listeners using [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage).

Inject code like this into the page

```
window.addEventListener('message', function messageInvoker(e) {
    if (e.data.extKey !== 'myKey') return; // some kind of check so you only worry about your own extension
    window[e.data.fn].apply(window, e.data.params);
}, false);
```

And from your extension,

```
window.postMessage({extKey: 'myKey', fn: 'userFunction', params: ['a','b','c']}, '*');
```

Comment: The documentation on the Developer site is a little confusing.  Can the messages posted from the embedding page to the extension access the page's execution environment variables?

Comment: You can pass transferable objects (read self contained) and most data types, i.e. _String_, _Number_ etc. also _ArrayBuffer_. If your object references another object or the environment it was in I'm not sure what happens.